# Module '"vee-validate"' has no exported member 'ValidationProvider'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to do a Local Registration of 'vee-validate".
but I get Module '"vee-validate"' has no exported member 'ValidationProvider'.

Here is what I did in my code :

**ContactForm.vue**

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component} from 'nuxt-property-decorator';
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
@Component({
    name : "ContactForm",
    components: {
        ValidationProvider, 
        ValidationObserver
    }
})
```

**package.json file**

```json
"vee-validate": "^3.4.13",
```

**vee-validate.js**

```js
import { extend } from "vee-validate";
import { email, required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "This field is required",
});

extend("email", {
  ...email,
  message: "Invalid email",
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart Editor and It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do make this kind of configuration globally, I guess it should work as good locally too

```js
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
```

Looking at the documentation, it looks like my method is only for a global use while yours should be okay for a local use.

Are you sure that you've added

```js
transpile: ["vee-validate/dist/rules"],
```

to your `nuxt.config.js` file?

### EDIT

Nvm, you've found the solution by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It's just by the editor, 
At least I got some new info from you